# Determine whether a set of vectors forms a root system

Tags: lie-algebras, root-systems

I have a set of vectors in the Euclidean space of dimension 4 (12 vectors),and
I would like to know how can prove whether this set is a root system of Lie algebra or not?

$  +/-{(e_i-e_j) } \space for \space {i\neq j}$
Where  $\space{e_i\cdot e_j =\delta_{ij}} \space for \space i,j=1,2,3,4$

Note: $(e_i-e_j)\cdot \sum_{k=1}^4 e_k = 0 $

Properties:

Let $\Phi$ be a set of vectors

1 - $\Phi$ does not contain zero, occupies a Euclidean space of the same dimension that classifies Lie G algebra and the number of elements of $\Phi$ is equal to dim , G - rank , G

2 - If $\alpha$ ; $\epsilon$ ; $\Phi$, the only multiples of $\alpha$ in $\Phi$ are  +/- $\alpha$

3 - If $\alpha$, $\beta$ , $\epsilon$ ; $\Phi$, so $\frac{2(\alpha \cdot\beta)}{\alpha^{2}}$ is an integer.

4 - If $\alpha$ , $\beta$  $\epsilon$ $\Phi$, then $\sigma_{\alpha}(\beta)$
exist in $\Phi$, that is, Weyl's group leaves $\Phi$ invariable

Comment: The obvious first thing to do is to write down what is the definition of a root system (and please write down the one you're working with, because there are equivalent but different ones around). Then if we are very formal, it is impossible to answer the question, because in that definition it will be demanded that a root system is more than just a set of vectors; you need to add some geometric input, e.g. how reflections act on them or how dual roots are defined etc. But I assume you assume we use the standard geometry from Euclidean space for that on these vectors?

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to put the properties that must be satisfied to be the root system, I couldn't prove it (especially the 3 and 4)

Comment: For 3, maybe you use different notation but I'd expect a norm in the denominator. But $\vert\vert \alpha \vert \vert^2 =2$ for all your vectors, so that cancels nicely the $2$ on top, and all you have to show is that the dot product of two of your vectors is an integer. Should be doable, if necessary write down some cases.

Comment: For 4, well how is $\sigma_\alpha$ defined?

Comment: $\sigma_{\alpha}(\beta)$ would be = $\sigma_{\alpha}(e_i - e_j) - \frac{2\alpha \cdot(e_i - e_j)}{\alpha^{2}}$ where $\beta = (e_i - e_j) $, 
then this account must be invariant as I understand it

Comment: That formula is wrong at at least two places. I'd expect $\sigma_\alpha(e_i-e_j) = e_i-e_j - \color{red}{\dfrac{2 \langle\alpha, e_i-e_j\rangle}{\lvert \lvert \alpha \vert\vert^2}} \cdot \alpha$ and what you have to show is that this expression is again a root, i.e. of the form $\pm (e_k-e_l)$. Note that the thing in red is a number, an integer, which you computed in 3. Your notation suggests you are not clear what is an inner product of vectors and what is scalar multiplication here, please look at that carefully again.